# Generate a new unique random session ID value at the server with each privilege change

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, cookies, sessionid

As per given query I'm trying to secure my financial website. In order to do so I require the ASP.net_SessionID to be changed after each privilege change i.e. ex. before login it should be "xyz" after loging "abc" and after logout "123".

I have tried below code to clear or change the ID on login button, logout button and on page load but all in vain.

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

please find exact requirement in a screenshot given below by client.

Any help would be really thankful.

[this image is a precise requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8MW.png)

Comment: In your WebConfig try this <sessionState regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"></sessionState>

Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")) =DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10)   then Check at your page load